# How to find which viewcontroller is using the extended viewcontroller class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, notifications

I have extended UIviewcontroller class to create a common corecontroller class for managing FCM in all viewcontrollers(Need to do some common function when FCM receive) .

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //registering gcm reciever
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(showReceivedGCMMessageCore(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: appDelegate.messageKey), object: nil)
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: appDelegate.messageKey), object: nil)
}
```

My extended Corecontroller class viewdidAppear and viewdiddisapper are above here i managed notification observer and removeobserver. 
After this wherever i required extended corecontroller class and inherited corecontroller class

// in my viewcontroller

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
}
```

But what i am missing is one viewcontroller is not removing the observer when disappearing (and due to this one functionality ie. playing a sound is talking place in background) Just want to know which viewcontroller is receiving the FCM. (in which viewcontroller class the FCM message is recieved)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `showReceivedGCMMessageCore` and see the backtrace.

Comment: To me it seems your problem is, that you have a Subclass of your `Corecontroller` which overrides `viewDidDisappear`, but does not call `super.viewDidDisappear`. Due to the limits of Xcode, you cannot search for overrides automatically, therefore you'll have to check your class hierarchy manually for `override func viewDidDisappear` without `super` call. Btw: In your `Corecontroller`, you also do not call `super`

Comment: @AndreasOetjen noted